# Reading files from grass into R with loop

Tags: r, grass-gis

I have a connection between GrassGIS and R. I want to read thousands files from my mapset into R. I have lines with names "line1","line2"...
I know I have to use a loop for this so I did

```
list_lines=list()
count=1
for (i in 1:3000){
    list_lines[count]=readRAST(c(line[i]),cat=c(FALSE))
    count=count+1
}
```

But it doesn't work. What should I do?

Comment: How was the "line" object created and what type of object is it (ie., vector, list)? I am assuming that it is a vector of GRASS raster names contained on disk, correct? What is the error you are receiving? The more information you provide the more likely a relevant solution will be provided.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few considerations here. Since you are reading so many rasters you will need to be aware of memory limitations. It would be good to know if your rasters share the same extent, resolution and row/column dimensions. If this is the case, and you must have an sp class object, you can avoid storing each raster as a separate object. The sp class SpatialPixelsDataFrame and SpatialGridDataFrame objects store raster values as a column in the @data slot. Because of this, if the rasters all match, you can have a single sp raster object with a column for each raster. So, in your case you would end up with a sp raster object with 3000 columns. That said, unless the rasters are small, RAM and performance issues will likely arise. An alternative to reading GRASS rasters and ending up with sp class raster objects is the readGDAL function in the rgdal package. You could set up a loop that reads each raster and then appends the @data slot data.frame with values for each subsequent raster. Code would look something like this (not tested):

```
library(sp)
library(rgdal)

# Read first raster and then append with subsequent raster values
r <- readGDAL(getwd(), lines[1])
  for (i in 2:3000){
    r.tmp <- readGDAL(getwd(), lines[i])
    r@data <- data.frame(r@data, r.tmp[,1])
  }
```

To directly address your original question. First, it is unclear where you are pulling your GRASS raster names from. Do you actually have a vector called "line" that represents the names? Looking at your code I believe that your main issue is that you are using single brackets to pipe the rasters into the "list_lines" list object. You already have an iterator "i" and do not need to define "count" and do not need c() to use a single value vector. I believe that this slight modification will work.

```
list_lines = list()
  for (i in 1:3000){
    list_lines[[i]] <- readRAST(line[i], cat = FALSE)
  }
```

Ideally, you want to come up with a solution using the raster package so the problem can be kept memory safe. Once again, if your rasters match you can simply use "stack" or "brick" to create a raster class object that is held out-of-memory and contains all of your rasters. If your rasters are different you can use the same basic idea as your original for loop but each of the rasters in the list object would be held out-of-memory.

```
library(raster)

# read all "common" rasters into single stack object
r <- stack(line)

# Loop through raster name vector and create list
list_lines = list()
  for (i in 1:3000){
    list_lines[[i]] <- raster(line[i])
  }
```

Having your rasters in a raster class will allow you to use the convenient raster processing functions available in the raster package (eg., overlay, focal, calc) and write custom functions that can be kept memory safe. Because, after all, once you have the rasters read into R you still need to do something with them.

Comment: You don't need here the  [rgdal](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgdal/index.html) package here because the [spgrass6](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/spgrass6/) or the [rgrass7](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgrass7/) packages allow to use R within a GRASS GIS session or use GRASS GIS within a R session (look at [GRASS wiki: R statistics](https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/R_statistics))

Comment: I am well aware of the spgrass 6 and 7 packages but you can think of it the other way as well, with rgdal or raster you do not need spgrass. With raster you can also keep the problem memory safe which is not the case with spgrass. Using gdal is also a bit faster on large rasters than spgrass and in this case may be an important factor.

Comment: That worked for me! You are right about the memory I never thought about it as it is my first time working with so many files!